# Can I use a macro to replace specific expressions within a block of code?

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to write a set of Rust macros to execute certain code in a special way. Currently, I am writing it like this.

```
macro_rules! macro_stmt{
    ([$e:expr]) => {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

and calling it

```
macro_stmt!([...]);
let var = macro_stmt!([...]);
macro_stmt!([...]);
// etc...
```

Which is great! Essentially, I am running an expression (the ellipsis are a placeholder for some unspecified code) inside the square brackets in a special way and the `macro_stmt` macro already works great.

What I would like to be able to do is write a macro so that I can run it like a block of code:

```
macro_rules! macro {
    // some rule to call macro_stmt!
    // this pattern isn't correct, BTW
    ($($line:stmt);+;) => {
        $(macro_stmt($line);)+
    }
}
```

and call it

```
macro! {
    [...];
    let var = [...];
    [...];
    // etc...
}
```

but the compiler yells at me for the `stmt` fragment not being correct syntax as the contents of the 'array' are not the correct comma-separated format.

Is there a way that I can call `macro_stmt` line-by-line without it checking syntax? The lines with no `let var =` would just call `macro_stmt()` but the lines with a `let` would prefix it with the same `let var = macro_stmt()`

The intended first expansion of `macro` would be

```
macro_stmt!([...]);
let var = macro_stmt!([...]);
macro_stmt!([...]);
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to fully understand your question. How literal is `[...]` supposed to be? Are the `[]` supposed to be literal and the `...` is an ellipsis denoting some unspecified code? Or do you want literally three `.` characters? Are you basically asking "inside this macro invocation, I want to specially handle every case of paired square brackets in a special way" ?

Comment: Yes, Apologies, the ellipsis is some unspecified code. Long day yesterday. I posted this just before bed.

Comment: please edit the question to show an example of code that could be between [...]